# Dynamically set method for tabPage

Tags: c#, winforms

I have TabControl. I added it to  tabpages. To one of them(tpTags) I dynamically add usercontrol tagsModule. When I'll click at tpTags I wanna to call method on tagsModule BindData

```
NEW CODE: 
  TabPage tpTags = new TabPage();
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tpTags);
    ...setting properties...
   TagsModule tagsModule = newTagsModule(_countryCode, ObjectType.Country);
 tpTags.Select() = tpTags.BindData(); //**How do it ??**

    tpTags.Controls.Add(tagsModule);
```

It could be: "how do I set an event that triggers when this tab is selected?"

Comment: What do you mean "set method `Select()`"? Do you mean "how do I select this tab?" ? Or do you mean "how do I set an event that triggers when this tab is selected?" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wire up the delegate to the event like this:

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Now you can put all your code inside this method

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(TabControl1.SelectedTab == tpTags)
    {
        // BindData();
    }
}
```

BindData() runs whenever your tabPage 'tpTags' is selected. If you want only for the first time, set a flag.

Comment: i don't understand your question now. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: I have TabControl. I added to it tabpages. To one of them(tpTags) I dynamically add usercontrol tagsModule. 
When I'll click at tpTags I wanna to call method on tagsModule BindData

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "how do I make this the current tab", then:

```
tabs.SelectedTab = tpTags;
```

If you mean "how do I respond when this tab is selected", then look at the `tpTags.SelectedIndexChanged` event (you don't necessarily need to care about the index when handling this event - you can just check `tabs.SelectedTab` again).